# Function making a series convergent

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have been trying to solve the following problem

> Assume $f : \mathbb{R} \to (0, \infty)$ is a function satisfying $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)}{x} = 0$. Prove that there exists a sequence $(x_n) \subset \mathbb{R}$ such that the series $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty x_n$ diverges, but $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty f(x_n)$ converges.

While the claim seems pretty obvious, I feel I lack the necessary intuition to prove it.

Comment: To *prove* the existence of such a series, you should exhibit an example. Do you know about $p$-series $\sum n^{-p}$?

Comment: @SammyBlack yes. I tried sequences like $\frac{1}{n}$ because the harmonic series would diverge, but $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty f(1 / n)$ not necessarily, but then a function like $f(x) = x \ln(1 + \lvert x \rvert)$ is a counterexample. The same would happen if we decreased the exponent of $p$-series further. I've also tried to prove it by contradiction, but nothing much has come out of that.

Comment: not obvious. Where did you get the problem?

Comment: @WillJagy it appeared in one of the tests at my uni last year. I'm practising for this year's one

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Functions such that $\sum \frac{1}{x_n}$ diverges $\Longrightarrow \sum \frac{1}{x_nf(x_n)}$ diverge](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1587247/functions-such-that-sum-frac1x-n-diverges-longrightarrow-sum-frac1)

Comment: (the linked question seems to be equivalent to yours)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to prove by contradiction, but here's a proof:

For every $k$, there exists $N_k$ so that whenever $0\leq x\leq \frac{1}{N_k}$ we have $f(x) < \frac{1}{k} x$. By enlarging $N_k$ if necessary we may assume $N_{k+1}>2N_k$.

For any sequence $x_n$, let $a_k$ denote the number of $n$'s where $x_n\in (\frac{1}{2N_k},\frac{1}{N_k})$. Then

$$\sum_n f(x_n) \leq \sum_k\frac{a_k}{N_k\cdot k}$$
because $a_k$ of the $x$'s are in $(\frac{1}{2N_k},\frac{1}{N_k})$ and so are at most $\frac{1}{N_k}$, but $f(x) \leq \frac{x}{k}$.

While for similar reasons $$\sum_n x_n \geq  \sum_{k} \frac{a_k}{2N_k}$$

Now we just need to choose $a_k$ properly. So we will just choose $a_k = \lfloor N_k/\sqrt{k}\rfloor$, these bracket denotes the largest integer smaller than $\frac{N_k}{\sqrt{k}}$, its a technicality because $a_k$ needs to be an integer. Namely, from any interval between $(\frac{1}{2N_k},\frac{1}{N_k})$ we will arbitrarily choose $a_k$ elements. This guarantees that

$$\sum_n x_n \geq \sum_k (\frac{1}{2\sqrt k}-\frac{1}{N_k})$$ Note that $\sum_k \frac{1}{2\sqrt{k}}$ diverges, on the other hand, since $N_{k+1}>2N_k$ we have $N_k>2^{k-1}$ which is huge, so $\frac{1}{N_k}$ is too small to change the divergence.

On the other hand
$$\sum_n f(x_n) \leq \sum_k \frac{1}{k^{1.5}}$$  which conveges.